# JS 2D массив loop

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Суть задачи такова: через Math.random создаем 6 массивов из 3 элементов. Затем эти массивы нужно поместить в массив a так, чтобы они не повторялись. Применить indexOf к 2D массиву, насколько я понял, нельзя. А если использовать if (a[i] != b) {a.push(b)} приведет к тому, что массив будет добавляться после каждого цикла.

```
var a = [];

for (let i=0; i<6; i++) {
  var b = [];
for (let j=0; b.length<3; j++) {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
  if (b.indexOf(rnd) === -1) {
    b.push(rnd)
  }
 }
 //здесь нужно дописать для a
}
```

Comment: "так, чтобы они не повторялись" - ??

Comment: Чтобы массив a содержал только уникальные, не дублирующие друг друга массивы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = [];
var lookup = [];
while (a.length < 6) {
  var b = [];
  while (b.length < 3) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
    if (b.indexOf(rnd) === -1) {
      b.push(rnd);
    }
  }
  if (lookup.indexOf(b + "") == -1) {
    lookup.push(b + "");
    a.push(b);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Интересный ход с b+""! Большое спасибо! Единственное, что не понял - зачем в console.log stringify?

Comment: ясно, еще раз спасибо!